# How can I have the Oracle 12c not auditing SYS-owned database trigger actions performed inside body?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-trigger

I have the following problem in an Oracle 12 c Release 2.

I have a Database Trigger on the After Logon system event created and owned by SYS. It inserts database connection custom audit logon records into a table, named AUDIT_LOGON (owned not by SYS).
If the user who is connecting to the database is under standard (Traditional) audit for INSERT TABLE, then a new record is created in the SYS.AUD$ table, related to the insert made by the Database trigger, but on the account of the connecting user - field USERID = connecting user.

As above said, the Database Trigger on After Logon is owned (and created) by SYS.
All actions performed inside it should generate no audit trail in standard audit trail table SYS.AUD$, as they are performed under SYS authority and as such unaffectable by the Standard (Traditional) Audit. 
Until Oracle 11g R2 everything is correctly, no record gets created in the SYS.AUD$ for INSERT (table) actions performed inside the DB trigger invoked by connecting users, while being audited for INSERT TABLE.

In 12c (R2 verified) I do get a record in the SYS.AUD$ for every insert on the AUDIT_LOGON table and (again) the connecting user is under INSERT TABLE audit.

This is not the expected behaviour, as the operations performed inside a trigger body owned by SYS are not supposed to generate anything on the SYS.AUD$!

Hints:

1. The illustration with the audited INSERT TABLE is just one case. the same would be if more system privileges would be audited to the user[s] and the DB Trigger would be performing them. In a real-life case, some of the connecting users are under full audit (all audit options) and the trigger more complex. Thus having tens (if not more) of records in the AUD$, for the actions inside the DB Trigger to have the single row in the custom logon audit table - is not acceptable.
   It was precisely this the reason that the DB Trigger is created (and owned) by SYS - to avoid extra trigger-internal logs in the AUD$. And it was working this way, correctly, until 11g R2.
2. the new (12c) field CURRENT_USER shows SYS in the use-case above

How can I have the 11g behaviour on the above?

at your disposal for further queries
best regards

Altin

USE-CASE-CODE:

```
-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = SETUP = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 

-- Create the audit repository schema user 
create user TESTREPO identified by manager
  default tablespace USERS
  temporary tablespace TEMP
  profile DEFAULT
  password expire
  quota unlimited on USERS;


-- Create the audit repository table
create table TESTREPO.AUDIT_LOGON
(
  logon_date DATE,
  username   VARCHAR2(100),
  hostname   VARCHAR2(200)
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );


-- Create the testing user 
create user TESTUSER identified by manager
  default tablespace USERS
  temporary tablespace TEMP
  profile DEFAULT
  password expire;
-- Grant/Revoke system privileges 
grant create session to TESTUSER;


-- Create Database After Logon Trigger as SYS (owned by SYS!)
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "LOGON_TRIGGER"
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

BEGIN
insert into TESTREPO.AUDIT_LOGON
values (sysdate, USER, SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'host')); 
END;
/

-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = SETUP = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 


-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = TEST PREREQUISITES = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 

-- Audit the TESTUSER for System Privilege INSERT TABLE
audit insert table by testuser by access;

-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = TEST PREREQUISITES = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 


-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = TEST = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 

1. Logon as TESTUSER 

2. Query the TESTREPO.AUDIT_LOGON table. A new record is created by TESTUSER - expected behaviour

3. Query the SYS.AUD$ table.  
Oracle 11g R2 and below:    NO standard audit record created by TESTUSER - expected behaviour 
Oracle 12c R1 and above:    Standard audit record IS created by TESTUSER - unexpected (!) behaviour

-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = TEST = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
```

Comment: Is unified auditing enabled?  Run this query to check: `select VALUE from V$OPTION where PARAMETER='Unified Auditing';`

Comment: Thank you Sir


the result of the command above is;

FALSE.


I have not changed anything in the Audit config after 12c install other then setting the Audit_Trail iniparam to DB,EXTENDED and audit the TESTUSER for INSERT TABLE.

The exact version of the Oracle is:

CORE 12.2.0.1.0 Production

best regards

Altin